# How long does it take Giants to respawn? Alternatively, where can I find a rapidly respawning Giant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to farm giants for their toes. Unfortunately they don't respawn very often. I've finished the main quest. Sometimes I wait up to 30 days for the respawn and they don't show up.

The location is marked as cleared
I left some mammoth last time
I wait 30 days
I am level 43

The giants do not respawn. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT*
Giant toes + wheat makes fortify health potion. While the potion is quite useful it levels up alchemy a lot

Comment: Are you dead set on a manual harvest? Touring Skyrim's alchemy shops might net you a sizeable bounty of toes faster.

Comment: Are you waiting within the same zone of the camp by any chance?  They won't respawn until the zone has been unloaded and you haven't entered it for some time.

Comment: @Eric Am really fascinated as to what you can do / make with a load of Giants toes. Are they for a potion maybe ?

Comment: I am not revisiting the camps. Unless simply travelling to cities is close enough to stop their spawn. I travel from town to town only buying all ingredients I can find

Comment: @Eric try traveling to a town more than half the map away and resting there for a while after you buy any toes you find. You need to rest pretty far from where the giants would respawn for it to happen. Bouncing between Markarth and Whiterun should be far enough.

Comment: Really?? Im making the same fortify health potion and i seem to find giants every new skyrim day. Try circulating between all of the camps and then rest a few days in say riften. I have about 60 giants toes saved at the moment (going for 100) but i cant find wheat.. Ive checked all the farms and found two with some wheat but that was all, and it hasnt respawned after 12 days.. Merchants and alchemist sell none either. Ive checked everywhere. If you do have a certain merchant or alchemist who sells it in quantities id be happy to know.

Comment: @Noah: Maybe it's different for every gamer? My giants and mammoth didn't respawn either even when I wait very long time. I often find some wheat in Solitude in the general and the alchemist store.

Answer (score 3):

I believe once you have taken down a Giants Camp (and it is confirmed as cleared on the map) it takes around 2 weeks (ingame) for the Camp to respawn - I read this somewhere when I was looking over Giant Camps for the toes too. However, they still roam freely around the open plains with mammoths. Its just a case of running around for a while until one spawns.

Answer (score 2):

It takes roughly twenty days in game...however, don't return to the giant camp during those twenty days or the respawn timer will reset itself for that individual camp.